# How do I make my transition smooth?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get my panel to smoothly change size whem I'm clicking on the date, but am stuck on how to do that. Here's my code:

```
<div id="top-nav">
    <div>
        <p class="text-right">
        Rozliczenie za okres: <span id="period_from" class="period" onmouseout="highlightPeriod()" onmouseover="highlightPeriod()" onclick="getNewPeriod()">
        24 <?= $data['okres']['od_miesiac'] . " " . $data['okres']['od_rok']; ?></span>
        do <span id="period_to" class="period" onmouseout="highlightPeriod()" onmouseover="highlightPeriod()" onclick="getNewPeriod()">
        23 <?= $data['okres']['do_miesiac'] . " " . $data['okres']['do_rok']; ?></span></p>
        <p id="period_selection" class="text-right hidden">
            <span id="period1">Od ... do ...</span><br>
            <span id="period2">Od ... do ...</span><br>
            <span id="period3">Od ... do ...</span><br>
            <span id="period4">Od ... do ...</span><br>
            <span id="period5">Od ... do ...</span><br>
            <span id="period6">Od ... do ...</span>
        </p>
        <p class="text-right">
             Dzisiaj jest: <span class="accent"><?= $data['dzienTygodnia'] . ', ' . $data['dzien'] . ' ' . $data['miesiac']; ?></span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the relevant css and js parts:

```
div#top-nav {
    height: 100px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
    position: sticky;
    top: -8px;
    background-color: rgba(242, 184, 9, 0.9);
    justify-content: space-around;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -3px gray;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #F37402;
    transition-duration: 2s;
}

p#period_selection {
    transition-duration: 2s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}


function getNewPeriod() {
    let el = $("#period_selection");
    $("#top-nav").css("height", "500px");
    el.css("display") == "none" ? el.css("display", "block") : el.css("display", "none");
}
```

Now, I had to give the `#top-nav` element the initial height, because without it the transition would not work at all, but that is causing the `#period_selection` text to show up BEFORE the div is fully transformed.

I tried to do this the other way, and apply the transition/size change to the `#period_selection`, but that did not seemed to have any effect at all - even when I applied some initial height to that element, there is no smooth transition and it all just pops in.

I have this strange feeling, that it may have something to do with the "display" property, but I can't put my finger on it.

How can I make this work?
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use max-height and overflow: hidden instead of height and display: none and apply it to the hidden content.

Overflow: hidden will take care the only text in expanded area is displayed.
And setting max-height will ensure a smooth transition.

I've modified your provided code:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="top-nav">
    <div>
      <p class="text-right">
        Rozliczenie za okres: <span id="period_from" class="period" onmouseout="highlightPeriod()" onmouseover="highlightPeriod()" onclick="getNewPeriod()">
        24<!--?= $data['okres']['od_miesiac'] . " " . $data['okres']['od_rok']; ?-->
          </span> do <span id="period_to" class="period" onmouseout="highlightPeriod()" onmouseover="highlightPeriod()" onclick="getNewPeriod()">
        23<!--?= $data['okres']['do_miesiac'] . " " . $data['okres']['do_rok']; ?-->
          </span>
      </p>
      <p id="period_selection" class="text-right hidden">
        <span id="period1">Od ... do ...</span><br/>
        <span id="period2">Od ... do ...</span><br/>
        <span id="period3">Od ... do ...</span><br/>
        <span id="period4">Od ... do ...</span><br/>
        <span id="period5">Od ... do ...</span><br/>
        <span id="period6">Od ... do ...</span><br/>
      </p>
      <p class="text-right">
        Dzisiaj jest: <span class="accent">
            <!--?= $data['dzienTygodnia'] . ', ' . $data['dzien'] . ' ' . $data['miesiac']; ?-->
          </span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <style>
    div#top-nav {
      padding: 5px;
      margin: auto;
      border-radius: 5px;
      display: flex;
      position: sticky;
      top: -8px;
      background-color: rgba(242, 184, 9, 0.9);
      justify-content: space-around;
      box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -3px gray;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #F37402;
    }
    
    p#period_selection {
      -webkit-transition: max-height 1s;
      -moz-transition: max-height 1s;
      -ms-transition: max-height 1s;
      -o-transition: max-height 1s;
      transition: max-height 1s;
      overflow: hidden;
      max-height: 300px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    p#period_selection.hidden {
      max-height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    function getNewPeriod() {
      let el = $("#period_selection");
      $("#top-nav").toggleClass("expanded");
      el.toggleClass("hidden");
    }
    function highlightPeriod() {
      //do fancy stuff here
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

For further details take a look at https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/

Comment: Thanks for the article! Reading it, I thought of another method - since I know there will only be six lines in that extra `<p>` I might as well just change its size with `overflow: hidden` - I'll try both solutions tonight when I come back home.